# VS CODE, how run python in OS terminal ? (Shell or CMD)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm programming (i try) in python with VS code.
On Windows and linux.

When i write a script an try to launch it, either on windows and linux the output is in a integrated terminal on vs code  the bottom of the windows.

My question is, when i press CTRL+F5 its possible to run my script automatcly on a CMD terminal  if i'm in windows and a Shell terminal if i'm in linux ?
( Open a new Terminal windows like Microsoft Visual Studio comunity )

i don't like the integrated terminal, and i prefere the OS terminal.

Thanks !

Comment: It may be possible, but I can see no reason for that. You should launch you script from VS only during development (and of course tests). As soon as it work, you should launch it *directly* from a terminal window with `python[3] path/to/script.py` for Linux or `py [-3] path\to\script.py` for Windows.

Comment: @Eva exe -How are things going? Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 3):

In VSCode, we can set the output mode of debugging Python. VSCode uses the internal terminal "`integratedTerminal`" by default, ("`Python Debug Console`").

For example, please use `"console": "externalTerminal",` in "[launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_initialize-configurations)" to set the output mode of debugging to VSCode's external terminal, that is, the cmd terminal of windows，then press Ctrl+F5 to debug the code:

[image]

Reference: [Debug console in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_console).